# Meteor crashes constantly even after reinstalling

Tags: meteor, crash, deploying

I am trying to run my project on the localhost but whenever I try it crashes. I even tried deploying it directly to the meteor website but nothing happens. It happened all of a suddenly. Everything was working fine till I added packages "tap:i18n" and "accounts-facebook".

```
    /Users/haraldur/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.1sd3e7j++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                    throw(ex);
                          ^ReferenceError: ServiceConfiguration is not defined
at lib/app.js:29:1
at /Users/haraldur/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/lib/app.js:47:4
at /Users/haraldur/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/haraldur/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.1sd3e7j++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at /Users/haraldur/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
```

Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

Answer (score 0):

This is my app.js file. I don't even have line 47. I am quite confused.

```
Timeouts = {};

// Initialize my collections
Rooms = new Meteor.Collection("rooms");
Videos = new Meteor.Collection("videos");
Messages = new Meteor.Collection("messages");
Votes = new Meteor.Collection("votes");
Favorites = new Meteor.Collection("favorites");
Skips = new Meteor.Collection("skips");

Cache = {};
Cache.Spotify = new Meteor.Collection("cache_spotify");
Cache.YouTube = new Meteor.Collection("cache_youtube");
Cache.Echonest = new Meteor.Collection("cache_echonest");
Cache.Freebase = new Meteor.Collection("cache_freebase");

// Dependencies for YouTube player
youtubeApiReady = false;
youtubePlayerReady = false;

youtubeApiDependency = new Deps.Dependency;
youtubePlayerDependency = new Deps.Dependency;

onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function(){
    youtubeApiReady = true;
    youtubeApiDependency.changed();
}

ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
  service: "twitter"
});
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
  service: "twitter",
  consumerKey: APIKeys.twitter.consumerKey,
  secret: APIKeys.twitter.secret
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the package `accounts-facebook` need specific configuration for it

try add `service-configuration` to your application

```
meteor add service-configuration
```

Reference https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/service-configuration

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I think I've finally solved it. The problem was that I had forgetten to kill mongodb so it was running in the background halting me from running my app.

Answer (score -1):

Since adding those two packages seem to be the culprit, try removing them one at a time. I would first:

```
meteor remove tap:i18n
```

And try to run it. If it still fails, try:

```
meteor remove accounts-facebook
```

...and try it again.

Alternatively or first, you might want to see what's at these two locations:

```
lib/app.js:29:1
lib/app.js:47:4
```

IOW, what's at line 29, char 1, and line 47 char 4 of your app.js file. Perhaps there is something problematic there, though if it worked prior to adding those two packages, likely not.